# Save URL as PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I have PDFs which I can access through URLs. I want to download and save it to files.
How can I go about it?
I actually need to parse the PDFs, if I cannot save it to a file can I get hold of it (as a PDF)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open a `URLConnection` to the URL.
2. Make sure that the status code is something successful (hopefully `200`).
3. Make sure that its contents is `application/pdf` or at least `application/octet-stream`.
4. Get the contents of the connection and write it to a `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

wget and curl are command-line utilities that do this. You could use Process to run them from Java as explained here: http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

There's likely a more native way to do it, though.

Comment: You actually mean "pure Java" rather than "more native".  In Java lingo, "native" usually means native to the OS platform ... not to Java.